# Save the data without using Preference and SQLite

Tags: android, json, offline

I am new to Android. I have some JSON data which I fetch by URL. I parse that JSON and show on UI. After that I want to access that parsed JSON data in offline. Is it possible without using preference or SQLite?

Comment: you can save it into file

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: Can we store parsed data? If yes then can you provide me a sample example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it to store on the web back again in a different place, if you want to store it on your device you can use, internal or external storage.

Comment: Can we store parsed data? If yes then can you provide me a sample example?

Comment: yup @User22791 pretty much answered it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it inside Global Class of your application that will store values application wide.

Create a class which `extends` `Application` and then create a public static variable inside it and then use that variable frequently to store and access the values.

**For example :**

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application {

    public static yourtype variableName; 

}
```

Comment: Are you sure, by this way we can store data offline just like SQLite? Whenever we open the application those stored data will be accessible?

Comment: @Dibya yes, I've used it in my apps.

Comment: Can you provide me a small example?

Comment: @Dibya sure. plz wait a while

Comment: Thanks @ User22791, will be try this one.

Comment: This is not persistent storage, so no, this data would not be available any time you open the application. Only while the process continues to live. When the process is killed and the classes are unloaded, any data here will be cleared from memory.